# Python - how can I read stdin from shell, and send stdout to shell and file

Tags: python, bash

I'd like to have a Python script read stdin from the shell (bash), and send stdout to shell as well a redirected file.  I tried the following:

```
$ cat test.py
#!/usr/bin/python

val = raw_input("enter val: ")
print val

$ ./test.py | tee out
testing
enter val: testing

$ cat out
enter val: testing
```

For some reason, the raw_input prompt is printed after I type my input, which means I can't see the prompt as I type.  With a bash script, I can get something similar to work.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter val: "
read val
echo $val

$ ./test.sh | tee out
enter val: testing
testing

$ cat out
enter val: testing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

print "enter val: ",
sys.stdout.flush()
val = raw_input()
print val
```

Or

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

sys.stdout = sys.stderr
val = raw_input("enter val: ")
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print val
```

Answer (score 1):

See this bug, looks like raw_input writes its prompt to stderr.

http://bugs.python.org/issue1927

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I tried the same thing as the OP, but used `print` to output the prompt, and the result was the same.

Comment: well it does it's just without the flush you see the same symptom - see tMCs answer