# Calling a a remote interactive python script from a bash script: Input request lag

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh, raw-input

I wrote a bash script that at one point automates the installation of some software on a remote host, like so:

```
ssh user@remotehost "<path>/install-script"
```

Where `install-script` is a bash script. That bash script at some point calls another bash script, which at some point calls an interactive python script, which then uses python's `raw_input()` function to gather user input.

When I run the install script normally (from a bash shell), it prompts for and accepts input perfectly fine. However, when the above piece of code from my script runs, I get no prompt until after I type the input.

The only script I really have control over is my automation script.

I have read this question: "[Python - how can I read stdin from shell, and send stdout to shell and file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218890/python-how-can-i-read-stdin-from-shell-and-send-stdout-to-shell-and-file)." However, I have no problem running in a normal bash shell, only via a remote command over ssh.

Can this issue be fixed from within my script (and if so, how?), or would I have to modify the python script?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, the input prompts I am referring to are the prompts from the python script. I am not entering a password for ssh (the remote host has my public key in it's `authorized_keys` file).

**UPDATE**

For further clarification, my script (bash) is calling the install script (bash) that calls another bash script that finally calls the python script, which prompts for user input.

i.e. bash -> bash -> bash -> python

Comment: You need to use subprocess.Popen or a ssh lib in order to achieve the input part.

Comment: Something along the lines of the code in my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472288/python-ssh-password-auth-no-external-libraries-or-public-private-keys/20472419#20472419

Comment: I'm aware, however the code in my problem handles input/ouput of a script via SSH. Note the `elif 'are you sure you want to continue connecting' in lower:` which is a example of when i give input back to the remote prompt. I've used it on remote installation scripts requiring some form of action/input from the user.

Comment: So you are saying that I would have to modify the python script (the one that is prompting), rather than my bash script?

Comment: I might have mixed things around, I assumed the calling script was Python and that the remote script was  bash->bash->python. But you're saying your calling script is bash?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I updated my question (I had forgotten to specify what sort of script my script was).

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh user@remotehost "<path>/install-script"
```

When you run `ssh` and specify a command to invoke on the remote system, by default ssh will not allocate a PTY (pseudo-TTY) for the remote session. This means that you will communicate with the remote process through a set of [pipes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) rather than a [TTY](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html).

When writing to a pipe, unix programs will typically buffer their write operations. You won't see output written to a pipe until the process writing to the pipe flushes its buffer, or when it exits--because buffered output is normally flushed on exit. Beyond that, a process can detect whether it's writing to a file, pipe, or tty, and it may adjust its behavior. For example, a shell like `bash` won't print command prompts when reading commands from a pipe.

You can force `ssh` to request a TTY for the session using the `-t` option:

```
ssh -tt user@remotehost "<path>/install-script"
```

Refer to the [`ssh` man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh) for details.